# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, odbc, 64-bit

I am trying to run a Java application that connects to a MS SQL Server 2008 database.  The application was always worked fine when run from a 32-bit machine.  The MS SQL database is and will remain on a 32-bit machine.  Only the java code is being moved to a 64-bit machine.

Now I have to migrate the java code to a 64-bit machine.  I got by the expected mismatched architecture errors by building the code with the 64 bit Java JVM, and using the 64-bit version of the SQL Native Client data source/driver.

Now, I am left with the error in the title, Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length.

I also installed the 32-bit JVM and SQL Native Client 10 on the 64 bit machine, and tried to run that way, and still a no go.

Will it be a problem, no matter what I do, to try to run a java app from a 64-bit machine that is trying to talk with MS SQL database on a different machine that is a 32-bit?

Thanks!!

Alex

Comment: This question may ask the same thing?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1954322/1254715

Answer (score 0):

May I know, Which OS are you using?? I hope you are using different OS in those machines. Though java is platform independent, MS SQL server is platform dependent. So that might be a problem.

I may be wrong too.